# How can I link a Redshift table to MS Access using VBA without encountering an ISAM error?

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc, amazon-redshift

Access cannot link to a table in AWS Redshift

I have an MS Access app that has linked tables from a locally installed SQL Server Express instance on the same PC.  I am testing out moving those tables to AWS Redshift.

I've recreated just one table in Redshift so far for testing.  I've created the DSN on my pc and I can connect with VBA using an ADODB.connection object and setting the connection string to the DSN.  If I try to link a table from Redshift to Access however using that DSN the Access app crashes every single time.  When I try to programmatically create the linked table using VBA I get an error "could not find installable ISAM", about which I have been able to find very little information online

I'm using Office 365 and version 2.00.00.06 of the Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver (x64)

This is the connection code I'm using.  The dbRSConn variable is a private variable in the same module.

```
Public Function GetRSConn(Optional ByVal TimeOut As Long = -1) As ADODB.Connection
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim strConn As String
    
    If IsEmpty(dbRSConn) Or dbRSConn Is Nothing Then
        Set dbRSConn = New ADODB.Connection
        dbRSConn.CommandTimeout = 0
        
        strConn = "DSN=CPP_RS"
        dbRSConn.ConnectionString = strConn
        dbRSConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        dbRSConn.Open
    End If
    If TimeOut <> -1 Then
        dbRSConn.CommandTimeout = TimeOut
    End If
    Set GetRSConn = dbRSConn
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        Resume
    End Select
End Function
```

When I test using `?GetRSConn.Execute("SELECT * from tblTest").RecordCount` in the immediate window I get the correct result.

When I try to link the table using the code below I get an error stating "could not find installable ISAM" at the TableDefs.Append step.

```
Sub TestLinkingToRS()
    Dim tdf As New DAO.TableDef
    Dim strConnectionString As String
    With CurrentDb
    .TableDefs.Refresh
    Set tdf = .CreateTableDef("tblTestRS")
    'strConnectionString = "Driver={Amazon Redshift (x64)};Server=serverstuff.amazonaws.com;Database=theDatabase;UID=theUserID;PWD=thePassword;Port=thePortNo"
    'strConnectionString = "DSN=CPP_RS;UID=theUserID;PWD=thePassword"
    strConnectionString = "DSN=CPP_RS"
    tdf.Connect = strConnectionString
    tdf.SourceTableName = "database.schema.tblTest"
    .TableDefs.Append tdf
    .TableDefs.Refresh
    End With
    Set tdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit-I've tried all three of the strConnectionString settings in the TestLinkingToRS() function

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Access x32, or x64 bits?

However, if you able to get the ADO in VBA (in access working with a conneciton to redshift, then you KNOW that a valid driver does exist).

This does suggest you have the correct ODBC drivers installed.

It not clear how you attempting to link (using external data + the wizards to create a connection).

I do suggest you try launching Access as administrator (the reason is the folders where the connection settings are saved often require elevated rights).

First try creating a FILE DSN. If that does not work, then try again and this time create a "Machine data source"

So, the default (tab) is a FILE dsn, and that is MUCH preferred.

However, I find a good number of drivers - even the sqlLite ones don't work (for some un-known reason) as FILE dsn, but do work when creating a SYSTEM dsn (A Machine data source).

So, launch access (tap windows key, type in access, and then do NOT click on the result, but right click and choose run as administrator.

At that point, choose from ribbon External data, ODBC database.

Use access to create the new connection (do NOT launch the ODBC panel from the control panel).

As noted, try first choosing to create a FILE connection. If that does not work, then try to create a Machine data source. As noted, you need/want to have launched ms-access as administrator.

Comment: I created the file DSN and still Access terminates a few seconds after confirming my login credentials.  I was running Access as Administrator.  Maybe there is something in the system logs as to why Access is crashing?  I doubt it and I'm not experienced with that activity but I'll try

Comment: the system log showed that the module that failed was ntdll.dll.  After searching for this online I found this mention in https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-access-crashes/9497b181-c628-4fd7-a9de-0a6e818dca88.  I'm going to make sure I have all the Office/Access patches installed and try again.

Comment: I found an alternate Redshift ODBC driver from devart that I'm testing out.  It's a little expensive so I'm just using the trial until I can confirm it works.  I was able to link the tables in Access so far and I'll be testing inserts updates and deletes later today.